# Update a Display Field value in extjs3 automatically

Tags: extjs, extjs3, taskmanager

I want to show current time on a window in my app which is written using Extjs. The time should be updated every one second but I don't know how to do it. this is my code:
Can anyone help me please?

```
function gettime(){
     var dt = new Date();
     dt = dt.format('h:i:s');
     return dt;
};

var clock = { 
    layout:'form', 
    frame:false, 
    region:'center',  
    height:100, 
    width:400,
    items:[{
         id: 'currtime', 
         xtype: 'displayfield',
         fieldLabel: 'Current Time',
         value:gettime()
     }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TaskManager](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.TaskMgr) for that:

```
// Start a simple clock task that updates a div once per second
var task = {
    run: function(){
        Ext.fly('clock').update(new Date().format('g:i:s A'));
    },
    interval: 1000 //1 second
}
Ext.TaskMgr.start(task);
```